# Hibernate ClassCastException IdentNode cannot cast to DotNode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am sitting with a ClassCastException while executing simple update query using JPQL.

Below is the exception trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AssignmentSpecification.<init>(AssignmentSpecification.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.evaluateAssignment(HqlSqlWalker.java:1133) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.evaluateAssignment(HqlSqlWalker.java:1127) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1042) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:747) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:367) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:255) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1777) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.SP1.jar:4.2.0.SP1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:425) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.1.Final-redhat.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat]
```

The query, I am executing is to move the task from the workpool:

```
public Boolean changeWorkpool(final TaskWorkpoolChangeRequest taskWorkpoolChangeRequest) {
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Task SET workpoolId = :workpoolId"
        + " WHERE taskId= :taskId");
    query.setParameter("workpoolId", taskWorkpoolChangeRequest.getWorkpoolId())
        .setParameter("taskId", taskWorkpoolChangeRequest.getTaskId());
    return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(query.executeUpdate());
}
```

Can someone please shed some on the cause of this exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the `Task` class plz.

Comment: Hey Ean, I was implementing entity mapping and trying with uni directional and bi directional joins in hibernate and when i changed uni to bi directional I missed to change workpoolId to the actual object workpool which caused the issue. Appreciate your intention to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter same problems recent days and I did some digging about the JPQL, found out that the JPQL update queries cannot update the relationship.

As it is stated in https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/queries.htm#OTLCG94000

> update queries can only update attributes of the object or its embeddables, its relationships cannot be updated.

I notice that the `Workpool` and `Task` may have a relation. So maybe it cause the problem.

Hope it helps.